# Shopify App Displays Blank Page on Shopify but Works When Iframe Link is Opened Directly

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-cli

I have successfully deployed and executed my application on a dedicated server. However, when I access the application through Shopify, it displays a blank page without any content. Intriguingly, when I inspect the Shopify admin iframe and directly open its source link in a browser, the application functions as expected, displaying all content correctly.

Could anyone please help me understand why this discrepancy between the Shopify environment and direct browser access is occurring? Any insights, diagnostic tips, or similar experiences shared would be greatly appreciated. I am looking to understand the potential causes and find a resolution to ensure that my application displays correctly within Shopify.

[image]

Comment: When app is loaded in the iframe did you see any error in the console?

Comment: I think the issue is related to Content Security Policy (CSP) and CORS but  I'm not sure which file to add it to, as I am new to Remix.js

Comment: If you created the app template from shopify cli then there is no need for CSP headers they are already added by default

Comment: @hamzasgd yes it was created from  shopify cli but I see some errors related in CSP in browser console

Comment: even sometimes when I refresh I also see them in console but that won't stop the app from rendering

Comment: @hamzasgd I don't see any errors other than CSP messages, and I can't find any documentation on how to fix them. Are you using Shopify CLI 3.50.0?

Comment: update your cli to latest version 3.51.1 and check again maybe it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### The Why

The CORs policy has become an integral part of the Shopify security.
You can refer to this [doc](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/store/security/iframe-protection)

This helps in ensuring that the content loaded into iFrame is from your trusted domain/shopify's admin domain only. ( Also know as Click-jacking. Read [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Clickjacking) )

### How to setup

Its fairly simple to set-up. In the server section, add a middle ware thats sets the `frame-anscestors` directive in all `response header`

#### For embeded apps

- `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://{{YOUR_MERCHANT'S_SHOP_NAME}}.myshopify.com https://admin.shopify.com;`
- This will tell the shopify's iFrame that the content is coming from trusted domain ( the shop's ) ✅
- If we have any other source of components being sent to front end, we should declare them too in the frame anscester. ( Just in case )

#### For non embeded apps

- We don't need the frame-anscestors directive. We can turn it off using

  - `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';`